# Power BI: "We cannot fold on top of this native query"

Tags: powerbi

Attempting to use a custom query to bring data into Power BI from a Postgress DB, I received the following error,

"We cannot fold on top of this native query. Please modify the native query or remove the 'EnableFolding' option"

Comment: Put some sample data and your expected output from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution in this situation was to simply remove the ending semicolon in the custom query.

Answer (score 0):

add the schema:

Select *
from PRD.Products